# How to update hostbinding which in turn should add class

Tags: angular

Given the following component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  style: [`
    :host.isSticky {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
  `],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.isSticky') isSticky = true;
}
```

And with this implementation:

```html
<my-component isSticky="false">
</my-component>
```

Is there a reason why the property is not updating and component is still sticky?

In the DOM I do see:

```html
<vf-molecules-notification-bar _ngcontent-lhu-c107="" issticky="false" _nghost-lhu-c92="" class="isSticky ng-star-inserted"></vf-molecules-notification-bar>
```

I've also tried:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  style: [`
    :host.isSticky {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
  `],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() isSticky = true;

  @HostBinding('class.isSticky') sticky = this.isSticky;
}
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[isSticky]="false"` because Without the brackets, Angular treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property to that static value and always this expression returns true